# How to sort collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to sort collection on parametr **n_text**?

```
abc = [108, [#<Advert id: 7095, user_id: 5, n_text: "First text", created_at: "2019-06-03 00:49:00", images_count: 0>, #<Advert id: 7096, user_id: 7, n_text: "Second text", created_at: "2019-06-03 08:23:00", images_count: 1>,...]]
```

`abc.order_by { |k, v| v[:n_text] }` dont working.

Comment: You want to sort the second element in the array? What’s the 108 in the top-level array?

Comment: It's unclear: `v` is an `Array` of `Advert` objects, please, show a more complete sample of `abc`. Do you want to sort `abc` or `v`?

Comment: `abc.last.sort_by(&:n_text)` would do.

Comment: ...or `abc.last.sort_by { |instance| instance(instance.instance_variable_get("@#{n_text}") }` if a getter has not been defined for `@n_text` (e.g., `attr_reader :n_text`).

Comment: What do you mean by `dont working`, what does it return? does it throw error?

Comment: Where is that collection coming from? A database query? Is that collection really a mix of simple integers (first element) and complex elements (all other elements)? Where should the integer be in the sorted result – still the first, last somewhere in the middle?

Comment: This collection from database query. 148 is category id - selection from array of cattegory.

Comment: "don't working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
abc.last.sort_by(&:n_text)
```

I think this will work, `.last` because you are going to sort last element of the `abc` array.